# What is making all divs with class .box stacking?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, pug, stylus

I'm making quick site to consume API with different news as an excercise. Until I've implemented logic in Angular it was allright (altough i doubt that Angular is the issue here). Thing is that all of properties that I've grabbed from url and displayed are stacked one on another causing visual gibberish. All except `{{article.title}}` which makes me guess it has something to do with css positioning.

You can see actual result 
[here](http://codepen.io/ketus/pen/jWMaMq) with code 
or 
[here](http://codepen.io/ketus/full/jWMaMq/) full page

Stylus code:

```
html, body
  width 100%
  height auto
  min-width 800px
  background url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Alien_Ink_2560X1600_Abstract_Background_1.jpg') no-repeat center fixed

.header
  //TODO

.grid
  padding 10px
  width 100%
  height auto

.box 
  background rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
  display inline-block
  width 300px
  height 400px
  margin 10px 5px
  box-shadow 0 2px 1px -1px

.image
  background-repeat no-repeat
  background-position center
  position absolute  
  width 300px
  height 200px
  box-shadow 0 2px 1px -1px 

.image > img



.author
  background rgba(255,255,255,0.4)
  position absolute
  right 0
  top 170px
  padding 5px 10px
  float right

.author > p
  margin 0 0

.info
  width 300px
  height 200px
  position absolute
  top 290px
  padding 10px

.title
  font-size 1vhmin 

.upVotes   
  position absolute
  top 170px

.date
  position absolute
  top 170px
  right 10px
```

Jade code:

```
main(ng-app='CamperNews')
  h1(style="text-align: center;") 
    | Camper News 
    a(href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/zipline-stylize-stories-on-camper-news' target="_blank")
      small FreeCodeCamps zipline
  .container-fluid(ng-controller='MainCtrl as ctrl') 
    .grid(ng-repeat="article in news")   
      span
        .box
          .image(ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{article.image}})'}")
            .author {{article.author}}
          .info
            .title
              p {{article.title}}        
            .upVotes 
              i.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart  {{article.upvotes}}      
            .date {{article.date | date:'dd MMMM yyyy on HH:mm'}}
```

Comment: you need to display boxes row wise?? i mean 4 in row like that?

Comment: Hard to tell what result you are aiming for. One of the issues are that the elements with `position: absolute` should have parents that are `position: relative`.

Comment: Something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbapJO ?

Comment: Should've included my intent, sorry. My aim was to make a "grid" with unlimited columns so I used spans. @tasseKATT Yes! that's the one. Did you only change .image position to relative?

Comment: obviously not. Did I mess something on fundamental level? What can I do to never deal with this again?

Comment: I changed `.grid` from `width: 100%` to `width: 320px`. Otherwise it would take the whole screen in width basically. Also made `.grid` float left so you get more than one on each row. Also removed most `position: absolutes`. Changed some paddings and some widths. If you need `position: absolute` just make sure the parent has `position: relative`.